# Friendly URLs in PHP

Tags: php

This is the URL path I currently use:

```
/index.php?pid=211

I want to get the URL path as

/index/211/title of the product
```

How to do user friendly URLs in PHP?

And how to get the value of the "title"?

Regards,

Comment: See [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you html code you must write like this:

```
<a href='http://www.domain.com/index/211/title-goes-here'>url_text</a>
```

and in the htaccess file adapt the following:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)$ index.php?action=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(member)-([0-9-]+)$ index.php?action=member&id=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)/([a-zA-Z-]+)-([0-9-]+)$ index.php?action=$1&saction=$2&sid=$3 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-]+)/([0-9-]+)$ index.php?action=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/(.*).html$ index.php?action=details&id=$1&p1=$2&p2=$3&p3=$4 [NC,L]
```

Comment: if you dont understand , please re comment

Comment: please write your htaccess code here and also the link that you are testing

Comment: echo '<a href=http://www.domain.co.uk/friendly_url/'; echo $info121['id_product']; echo "/"; echo $info121['name']; echo '>'; echo $info121['name'];echo' </a>';

Comment: ok, just adapt one of the rules from the htaccess file in order to best suit your link, like this: RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ your_file.php?action=details&id=$2